# Complex SQL query issue (MYSQL Workbench 6.3)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having trouble figuring out how to write this query.
Let me explain the situation.

So, the question,
I need to display all the player names who have scored a score greater than 99, who have played matches in all the same grounds where a certain player (e.g. pid = 1) has played and has scored a score greater than 99.
(They could have played in other grounds besides the one pid = 1 has played, but the minimum requirement being they must have played in all the same grounds as him).

I have a database, which consist of 3 tables; player, ground, matches. And following data.

```
create database test1;
use test1;

CREATE TABLE `player` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pname` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `ground` (
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `player` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pid`);

ALTER TABLE `ground` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`gid`);

ALTER TABLE `matches`
  ADD KEY `gid` (`gid`),
  ADD KEY `pid` (`pid`);

INSERT INTO `player` (`pid`, `pname`) VALUES
(1, 'afridi'),
(2, 'kohli'),
(3, 'imam'),
(4, 'fawad'),
(5, 'baven'),
(6, 'awais');

INSERT INTO `ground` (`gid`, `gname`, `country`) VALUES
(1, 'Qaddafi', 'PK'),
(2, 'National', 'PK'),
(3, 'Eden Garden', 'IND'),
(4, 'Lords', 'ENG'),
(5, 'MCG', 'AUS'),
(6, 'Arbab Nayyaz', 'PK');

INSERT INTO `matches` (`pid`, `gid`, `score`) VALUES
(1, 2, 23),
(1, 1, 111),
(2, 3, 107),
(2, 5, 103),
(1, 3, 117),
(1, 4, 55),
(1, 5, 101),
(1, 6, 44),
(2, 6, 103),
(2, 4, 103),
(2, 2, 117),
(2, 1, 103),
(4, 1, 77),
(3, 1, 13),
(5, 2, 22),
(3, 2, 101),
(3, 3, 101),
(5, 1, 101),
(5, 4, 101),
(5, 5, 101),
(6, 1, 101),
(6, 2, 101),
(6, 3, 101),
(6, 4, 101),
(6, 5, 101),
(6, 4, 101);
```

Relatively a simple database.

I've written the following query which displays the names of 4 players. It is displaying all the players who have played in the same grounds as pid = 1. How to display **only** those players which have played in all the same grounds as pid = 1.

```
select p.pname 
from player p
join matches mn on mn.pid = p.pid
where (p.pid != 1) and (mn.score > 99) and exists (select m.gid from matches m where (m.pid = 1) and (mn.gid = m.gid))
group by pname;
```

According to the data provided in the tables,
Afridi (pid = 1) has scored century in the following grounds; 1, 3, and 5.

Respectively, players (pid) 2, 3, 5 ,6 have scored century in grounds = 1, 3, and 5.

These players have made centuries in other grounds as well but this query displays all players who have played in any of the 3 grounds.

The players could've played in other grounds as well, but the minimum requirement being that the players have to play in all the grounds; 1, 3, 5.

So, what I need is, only **all** those players, which have played in all of the same grounds, as in grounds; 1, 3, 5.

From observing the data in table matches we can see the players that have played in all the same grounds are only 2, being pid = 2, 6.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Take a look at the links in my comment above. They will explain what you need to add to your question to get an answer. Specifically, what SQL statement have you tried so far?

Comment: Lastly, if you include your sample data as code (instead of an image) in your question, we could create a SQL fiddle to show you a solution.

Comment: Who you calling we kemosabe

Comment: @SloanThrasher thanks for the help. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query should do what you want. It creates a table of grounds where the first player has played and made a century (`g1`), and joins that to the players who have also played at those grounds. If the number of different grounds that the other player has played at is the same as the number of different grounds that the first player has played at, they must have both played at the same set of grounds. Note there are a couple of places (in both subqueries) where you need to set the player id for comparison.

```
SELECT p.pname
FROM (SELECT gid, pid FROM matches WHERE pid=1 AND score >= 100) g1
LEFT JOIN matches m
ON m.gid = g1.gid AND m.pid != g1.pid
JOIN player p
ON p.pid = m.pid
GROUP BY m.pid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.gid) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gid) FROM matches WHERE pid=1 AND score >= 100)
ORDER BY m.pid
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a48f10/30)